# What is better? Using 'base_url()' or './'?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been using CodeIgniter Framework for some months.

In views, I usually include external css and js with `base_url()`, just like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But someone tells me that using `./` also works too. And that's true.

So, what is better ( in security )?

Comment: You must set your base url on the config.php because if you do not some links will not work properly images, css etc.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Thanks for your advice, sir. I've done it.

Comment: Another tip: It says to put `/` at end `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/'` some people do and some people don't but it what comment says above that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

base_url() is a better choice to use.
There isn't a cost difference using a relative or complete url, and this way you know it will point to the right spot.

It's a better habit to be in, and you can pass URL parameters to it and keep code neat.

Answer (score 2):

`base_url()` is just a helper (URL helper in CI). Some people just find it easier to use, so I don't see any added security by using `base_url()`.

In case of ease of use, I see so many people use it like

```
<?php echo base_url()."controller/function";?>
```

while actually you can use it like

```
<?php echo base_url("controller/function");?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can used either, but its a good practice in **Codeigniter** to use base_url().

Answer (score 1):

you can use use `./` instead of `base_url()`. **./** is the root directory of your codeIgniter installation and it will get that bath in most cases that are same as `base_url()`, but `base_url()` is best practice to use because in some server `./` does not work or some other issue.

Comment: Are both same in security aspect?

Comment: In security aspect base_url() is best and ./ is not good because you are exposing your main root directory. You can also check details here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65700/is-it-safe-to-add-to-my-path-how-come